# Rain Water problem in Python: iterating backwards while comparing indices

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working through the rain water problem in Python. My input array is `a = [4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2]` and I'm attempting to iterate through that array while concurrently creating a new array `left_maxes` where each index represents the highest value so far in `a`. After that, I will iterate through `a` backwards and use the same process as before, creating `right_maxes`.

```
a = [4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2]

def optimized_rain_water(histogram):
  total = 0
  left_maxes = []
  right_maxes = []
  for i in range(len(histogram)):
    max_value = histogram[0]
    if histogram[i] > max_value:
      max_value = histogram[i]
    left_maxes.append(max_value)
  for j in range(len(histogram)):
    max_value = histogram[-1]
    if histogram[j] > max_value:
      max_value = histogram[j]
      right_maxes.reverse()
    right_maxes.append(max_value)
  print(left_maxes, right_maxes)
```

When I call the function it should return `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]` and `[4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2]` but I can't get `right_maxes` to reverse correctly. I have tried moving `right_maxes.reverse()` to the end of the loop or iterating through `histogram` backwards in that same loop and I always end up with an array of one 4, one 3 and five 2s in some order. The end goal is to compare these two arrays but I can't get that far because I know that `right_maxes` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is, why you are assigning `max_value` inside a loop. It is going to be `static` for a given `loop`, so take it outside before `iterating` the `loop`
Another thing is, why are you using `right_maxes.reverse()` inside a loop, it will reverse this list at each `iteration`.
Another thing is, you need to `reverse the loop` for the `right_maxes` to start comparison from `right to left`
And then finally, you need to `reverse` the `right_maxes` to get what you are looking for.

```
a = [4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2]

def optimized_rain_water(histogram):
  total = 0
  left_maxes = []
  right_maxes = []
  
  max_value = histogram[0]
  for i in range(len(histogram)):
    if histogram[i] > max_value:
      max_value = histogram[i]
    left_maxes.append(max_value)
  
  max_value = histogram[-1]
  for j in reversed(range(len(histogram))): #range(len(histogram)):
    if histogram[j] > max_value:
      max_value = histogram[j]
      #right_maxes.reverse()
    right_maxes.append(max_value)
  right_maxes.reverse()
  print(left_maxes, right_maxes)

>>optimized_rain_water(a)
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] [4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead for the code to right maxes ,as you are iterating backwards:

```
for j in range(len(histogram)-1,-1,-1)
```

Comment: Should be `range(len(histogram)-1,-1,-1)` as the end index is not inclusive (o), need to use `-1` so that the last index checked is 0. (Try printing out `j` in that loop to see what numbers are iterated over).